# JPA @Query gives NonUniqueResultException

Tags: java, jpa

i have entity like this

```
@Builder
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "fulfillment_purchase_orders")
public class FulfillmentPurchaseOrder extends Audit implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "purchase_order_id")
    private Integer purchaseOrderId;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;
```

but i want to get the latest data from version. i have try use this code :

```
@Query("select f from FulfillmentPurchaseOrder f where f.purchaseOrderId =?1 order by f.version desc")
    Optional<FulfillmentPurchaseOrder> findByPurchaseOrderId(Integer purchaseOrderId);
```

but i got error like this

```
query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2",
```

my question is how to make query for getting only the latest use order by Version ?

Comment: Try to select the first record, e.g. using some form of `limit` or using a subquery to select the "max" order - or using `findFirst...` or `findTop...`.

Comment: @Thomas JPQL doesnt support LIMIT I think

Comment: @VinayHegde yes, that's why I changed to "some form of limit" (if `setMaxResults` could be used that would be an equivalent) and added alternatives. :)

Comment: yes. he can also go with `pagerequest`

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning more then one result. Try making the query native and adding `LIMIT 1` at the end like so:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select f from FulfillmentPurchaseOrder f where f.purchaseOrderId =?1 order by f.version desc LIMIT 1")
    Optional<FulfillmentPurchaseOrder> findByPurchaseOrderId(Integer purchaseOrderId);
```

`LIMIT 1` means return the first row that matches.

Comment: Will this work ?

Comment: @VinayHegde LIMIT can be used when `nativeQuery` is set to true

Comment: Okay. but if nativeQuery is true then its not a JPQL its a sql statement isn't it ?

Comment: @VinayHegde, I guess so. Why?

Answer (score 0):

use subquery like :

```
@Query("select * from FulfillmentPurchaseOrder f where f.purchaseOrderId = (SELECT max(fp.purchaseOrderId) FROM FulfillmentPurchaseOrder fp)")
    Optional<FulfillmentPurchaseOrder> findByPurchaseOrderId(Integer purchaseOrderId);
```